# How to integrate Facebook Login with your website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to provide the option to login through facebook on my website where the user can go and login through facebook itself instead of registering himself on my website and then logging in?

Comment: No, no idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation by Facebook on how to integrate facebook login to your website:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/
```

Remember, the easiest way to do it is using Facebook JavaScript SDK, you can find here the reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Hope it helps :)